# How to display a group of multiple elements dynamically in java?

Tags: java, user-interface, dynamic

When i click the button i need to display a group of Labels, TextFields and Buttons dynamically depending on the number that i get from the spinner.

[Spinner and A Button for choosing the number of elements groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZy05.png)

For example if the value of the spinner is 2 (in the image above), it must display the elements like that when i click the button:

Label A - Textbox A1 - Textbox A2 - Button A

Label B - Textbox B1 - Textbox B2 - Button B

Comment: Do you have some existing code for what you have so far that you can post here?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.